# Programmatically enumerate outgoing Segues for a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

For iOS 5 navigation between view controllers, the `UIViewController` Class provides `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender]` selector. Presumably, under the hood, the storyboard implementation knows the list of segue identifiers outgoing from any view controller, i.e. `[@"MySegue", @"MySegue2"]`. Is there any way to access this list programmatically, to get the identifiers that can be passed to performSegueWithIdentifier?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an undocumented behaviour but

```
NSArray *segueTemplates = [self valueForKey:@"storyboardSegueTemplates"] ;
```

should return an array that includes all possible segue values that can be passed to `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Seems validated elsewhere: https://gist.github.com/away4m/5bb5d773cb93aa9e60a1 - thanks Rog!

Answer (score 10):

There is no public API for enumerating the segues in a storyboard.

Comment: Sad. So my only option is to catch the exception if it throws... That's not like Apple.

Comment: I would like to reassess this with ios9 [though my hope is slim :D]

Answer (score 2):

For Objective-C, I used to use this if I knew the segue name.

```
- (BOOL)isValidSegueId:(NSString *)segueId {
    NSArray *filteredArray = [[self valueForKey:@"storyboardSegueTemplates"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier = %@", segueId]];
    return filteredArray.count > 0;
}
```

Swift:

```
    func isValidSegueId(_ segueId: String?) -> Bool {
    let filteredArray = (value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? NSArray)?.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "identifier = %@", segueId ?? ""))
    return (filteredArray?.count ?? 0) > 0
}
```

You can combine that with this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35060917/1058199 to get all the segues for the current view controller and validate each.

Answer (score -2):

Store all the `segue` related to the view controller in an array and then access this array in the view controller.

Comment: All the segue**s**.