# Get list of all segues connected to a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm writing a test for one of my ViewControllers. I need to make sure that the controller does have all of the segues it is supposed to have according to the design.

I have not been able to find information on how to do this.

Comment: I just poked around docs and google (probably what you did), and found no help.  It might be that that test can be implemented only manually, by desk checking your storyboard.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid test. I can't see a way that a view controller will loose a segue. You should check if the view controller's class is the right one, if it's the right one then it will have the proper segues.

Comment: @danypata It can loose it when someone removes it, in which case I want to be notified.

Comment: @Pétur Then you can encapsulate the `perfromSegue...` method from your `UIViewController` into a `try catch` block, if there is an exception thrown then your segue was removed ;)

Comment: @danypata Works, can u post it as an answer so I can close this.

Comment: @Pétur I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment, in order to find which segue is missing, you can encapsulate the `performSegue...` method of your `UIViewController` into a `try catch` block, if there is an exception thrown then one of your segue has been removed. (The one that tries to perform)

Comment: You're at risk of memory leaks and other badness if you continue normal execution after UIKit throws an exception.

Comment: @JoshCaswell What I suggested was not for "production" code, it's more fore find & debug issues.

Comment: Fair enough! I came across this answer while writing tests for a storyboard myself.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Programmatically enumerate outgoing Segues for a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206257/programmatically-enumerate-outgoing-segues-for-a-uiviewcontroller), it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately information about which segues exist is stored in `UIStoryboard`'s internal view graph and inaccessible using public APIs. There's no way to get a hold of this information in a way that would still let you publish on the App Store.

That said, looking for a specific, named segue is kind of a brittle way to write that test. Ideally you'd write something like this as an integration test which ensures that, given the user performs some action, the expected view controller is presented.

Comment: Why are segues hidden?